# Django Record datetime with timezone

Tags: django, datetime, timezone

I'm having trouble with timezone time recording.

I have on settings.py:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'
USE_TZ = True
```

I have in model:

```
hour = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
```

In the template I get string time 10:00:00:

```
{% load tz %}
{% localtime on %}
10:00:00
{% endlocaltime %}
```

Before saving convert the string to datetime:

```
form = Form(request.POST)
data = form.data
tz = get_current_timezone()

hour = "01-01-2019 {}".format(data.get("hour"))
hour = tz.localize(datetime.strptime(hour, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

When returning to the template, it is show 12:00:00:

```
{% load tz %}
{% localtime on %}
12:00:00
{% endlocaltime %}
```

Something is wrong while recording.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I'm guessing this is because of your date: January 1, 1900. Perhaps that was indeed the difference from UTC then. If that's not what you want you should specify a date or simply use a `TimeField`.

Comment: Yes, I think the date 1900 is a mistake. I am changing this.

Comment: I think timefield doesn't register timezone. 
I am wrong?

Comment: I edited the question. There has been progress.

Comment: You should include the actual code in your template that is displaying the time. Presumably you are stripping off the date, meaning that you are no longer showing a `DateTimeField`, meaning that Django cannot convert to the local time zone for you. More generally, though, this whole idea of using a fake date is almost surely the wrong thing. Just use a `TimeField`. If you're just presenting the time, the time zone is meaningless, and if you're combining it with a date, the localization needs to happen then.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I will review the project. Thanks!